# AzurePowerShell@4 - powershell commands fail to execute on azure pipeline

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines

As a part of my yml pipeline definition, I have a AzurePowerShell@4 task, following is an extract from my pipeline definition

```
stages:
- stage: DeployDemoCluster
  jobs:
  - job: 'DeployAKSAndAll'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps: 
      - task: AzurePowerShell@4
        displayName: Store AI instrumentation key for Inbound Processor in central KeyVault
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'service-connection'
          azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
          pwsh: true
          ScriptType: 'FilePath'
          ScriptPath: 'AKS/ps/update_kv_firewall.ps1'
```

The issue is, within my update_kv_firewall.ps1, all the powershell commands fail with the error, for example:

> [error]Login-AzureRmAccount : The term 'Login-AzureRmAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

The script when executed individually / standalone, works perfectly fine.

what am I missing here?

Comment: I managed to bypass the login issue, but it fails on the next command anyway, error being : "##[error]The term 'Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Comment: It seems like some commands run without an issue. For example, the command "Get-AzKeyVault" runs without any errors, while 'Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork' leads to errors. Any links to indicate what are the limitations here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment: the command "`Get-AzKeyVault`" runs without any errors, while '`Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork`' leads to errors.

Then I'm sure that you're installing the new [Az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-3.3.0#install-the-azure-powershell-module-1) of azure powershell. So the command like `Get-AzKeyVault` can work.

Since you're installing Az module, please use all the commands from Az module. Almost each `azure Rm command` has an equivalent `azure Az command`, you can find it from the [Az command list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvault?view=azps-3.3.0).

Note: the command like `Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork` / `Login-AzureRmAccount` is from [azure RM module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-6.13.0), which will be retired this year later.